# How do I convert from Microsoft Word to PDF while preserving hyperlinks?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2011

The links are blue and underlined, but the link is not preserved. I'm aware of freepdfconverter, but I was hoping of some other way which does not require me to put my document up on the web.

Comment: What version of Office are you using? Since Office 2010 you can do "Save as..." and then choose "PDF" file format, no external tools required. And it does preserve hyperlinks.

Comment: I'm on Word 2011.

Comment: Free Nitro PDF reader also has a printer driver that would show in Word, and in my experience URL links are preserved.

Comment: I can confirm that @MBu's tip works as expected on Microsoft Word 2011.